# Проверочные сообщения в очереди предлагаемых правок появляются с явной задержкой

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

Ни для кого не секрет, что в очереди проверок предлагаемых правок бывают проверочные сообщения - чтобы люди не жали "принять" на всё подряд.

Эти сообщения достаточно очевидны (вставлено несколько кусков несвязанного текста), но какую-никакую защиту от ботов наверно обеспечивают. Но в последнее появилась еще одна дополнительная яркая примета: обычные правки появляются почти сразу после принятия/отклонения предыдущей правки, а проверочные - с задержкой на несколько секунд (как будто сервак подгружает их из свопа), что в последнее время служит практически 100% признаком.

Вопрос - откуда берется эта задержка, и можно ли ее устранить?

Comment: Этот робовандализм настолько заметен, что я и раньше его с первой секунды распознавал. :) Но наблюдение интересное.

Comment: Задержка настолько явная, что я уже заранее мышь двигаю на пипу "отклонить".